# Unsure as to how to go about deleting the (highlighted/selected row) in table

Tags: javascript, dom, row

How do I go about either modifying the existing Javascript code or add some code to be able to have the option to delete the highlighted (selected row) from my HTML table at the click of a button?

The use of jQuery is framework also fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table Row Demo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
tr.normal td {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
tr.highlighted td {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    test()

}

function test() {

    var trows = document.getElementById('mstrTable').rows, t = trows.length, trow, nextrow,
    rownum = document.getElementById('rownum'),

    addEvent = (function(){return window.addEventListener? function(el, ev, f){
            el.addEventListener(ev, f, false); //modern browsers
        }:window.attachEvent? function(el, ev, f){
            el.attachEvent('on' + ev, function(e){f.apply(el, [e]);}); //IE 8 and less
        }:function(){return;}; //a very old browser (IE 4 or less, or Mozilla, others, before Netscape 6), so let's skip those
    })();

    rownum.value = rownum.defaultValue; //reset for browsers that remember input values on reload

    while (--t > -1) {
        trow = trows[t];
        trow.className = 'normal';
        addEvent(trow, 'click', highlightRow);
    }//end while

    function highlightRow(gethighlight) { //now dual use - either set or get the highlighted row
        gethighlight = gethighlight === true;
        var t = trows.length;
        while (--t > -1) {
            trow = trows[t];
            if(gethighlight && trow.className === 'highlighted'){return t;}
            else if (!gethighlight){
                if(trow !== this) { trow.className = 'normal'; }
                else if(this.className === 'normal') { rownum.value = t; }
                else { rownum.value = rownum.defaultValue; }
            }
        }//end while

        return gethighlight? null : this.className = this.className === 'highlighted'? 'normal' : 'highlighted';
    }//end function

    function movehighlight(way, e){
        e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        var idx = highlightRow(true); //gets current index or null if none highlighted
        if(typeof idx === 'number'){//there was a highlighted row
            idx += way; //increment\decrement the index value
            if(idx && (nextrow = trows[idx])){ return highlightRow.apply(nextrow); } //index is > 0 and a row exists at that index
            else if(idx){ return highlightRow.apply(trows[1]); } //index is out of range high, go to first row
            return highlightRow.apply(trows[trows.length - 1]); //index is out of range low, go to last row
        }
        return highlightRow.apply(trows[way > 0? 1 : trows.length - 1]); //none was highlighted - go to 1st if down arrow, last if up arrow
    }//end function

    function processkey(e){
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 38: {//up arrow
                return movehighlight(-1, e)
            }
            case 40: {//down arrow
                return movehighlight(1, e);
            }
            default: {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }//end function

    addEvent(document, 'keydown', processkey);
    addEvent(window, 'unload', function(){}); //optional, resets the page for browsers that remember the script state on back and forward buttons

}//end function
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  Current Row: <input type="text" id="rownum" value="None" readonly>
  <table id="mstrTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <thead>
      <tr> 
        <th>File Number</th>
        <th>Date1</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Num.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr> 
        <td>KABC</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>09/12/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>1</td>

      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>KCBS</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Lockdown</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr> 
        <td>WFLA</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>09/11/2002</td>
        <td>Submitted</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>WTSP</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>09/15/2002</td>
        <td>In-Progress</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="delete this row" onclick="delete_row()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

this seems to work, once the row number seems to accounted for.

```
function delete_row() {

    var r = document.getElementById("rownum").value

    document.getElementById("mstrTable").deleteRow(r);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this (if you know the row number)

```
function delete_row() {

    var r = document.getElementById("rownum").value

    document.getElementById("mstrTable").deleteRow(r);

}
```

Comment: if no row is selected, it deletes the header row or the last row depending on the browser

Answer (score 0):

This only deletes a row that is selected. No need to pass in the row number.

```
function delete_row() {    
    document.querySelector(".highlighted").remove();    
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsbin.com/gubuduli/3/edit?html,output